# What is the biggest a font can be for optimal legibility

Tags: font, font-sizes

I'm reviewing a site design and the hero image has a font size of 53px, which feels uncomfortably large, especially for longer titles.

Is there a limit to how big titles should be on the web? i.e. are there any guidelines around this?

Comment: this question is absolutely relative. I have used 72px font sizes without problems, even up to 120px (so more than 200% over what you perceive as *uncomfortable*). It depends on many things, starting from style, emotional aspects, screen size, device, resolution, font family, color, contrast and so on. I did a quick test: styled the title of this post with 53px font size. It looks nice, nothing really astonishingly big. And it's not even a hero image supposed to use much bigger sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would be helpful to the designer is if you can tell them *why* it appears to be uncomfortably large, in your estimation. Often, I find that it's not the actual point-size of the text alone that makes it uncomfortable. Off the top of my head, here are some reasons why a large font size might make the text seem uncomfortable to read:

- The heading is broken onto **several lines**; flicking the eyes from one end of a large screen to the other can be an uncomfortable experience, especially if there are only a handful of words per line
- The **visual composition is unbalanced**—that is, the heading draws undue attention and makes it uncomfortable to try and look at *other* things on the page. This might be exaggerated if the headline is also the brightest color, has the sharpest contrast, etc.
- Perhaps the large text **obscures the hero image too much**, or gets uncomfortably close to a prominent element of the image, creating a **[tension point](http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/visual-tension/)**
- It could be uncomfortable to read the large text if **the eye [has to move several times to read long words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_movement_in_reading)**

To your question about existing standards for type sizes, the answer is no, I don't think there are any standards for *upper* limits to point size. ([There are accessibility guidelines that describe a minimum legible font size, though.](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html#larger-scaledef))

It never hurts to voice your concerns, and let the designer decide how to address the issue. (The whole point of a critique is to improve the work, after all.) Don't forget, there is probably a reason they made the hero text that big, so provide as much detail as you can about the **problem**, but try not to be prescriptive about the **solution**.

---

If you're looking to read up on this further, I recommend starting with  the article ["Responsive Typography: the Basics" by iA](https://ia.net/know-how/responsive-typography-the-basics). They do a pretty good job of explaining the variables involved with designing typography for the web.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it has clarified things quite a bit for me. I think the main issue for me was that the lines of text typically split over two lines which for relatively short sentences led to what i felt was bad legibility. The balance of visual composition is another issue. Thanks your answer seems to have conceptualised my feelings

Answer (score 0):

From a cognitive perspective what matters is the size of the projected text on the retina, which involves:

- Font size
- Display size
- Display resolution
- Distance of the display from the eyes

So there isn't really a gold standard, what will appear small to some will appear large to others.

Obviously, this doesn't apply if you know the screen size/resolution/position like you would with airport information screens - there you can work out legibility based on distance.